# Thunderbird opens twice always

Tags: thunderbird

I have Thunderbird on Ubuntu 12.04 and every time I open it, it loads twice. Two windows are opened.

To be clear, if I have Thunderbird closed (not minimized) and click on Mail, in the tray bar, it opens 2 main windows.

I have had installed several add-ons, including FireTray and "Minimize to Tray Revived", but now I have removed all of them. Actually I can disable all the add-ons and it still happening.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Disable "MinimizeToTray Plus" in menu "Tools/Add-Ons"
2. Exit Thunderbird (be sure that the process is not running)
3. Open Thunderbird (in my case, I had the same two windows problem the first time)
4. Now Thunderbird runs without the MinimizeToTray Plus add-on
5. Close one of the window
6. Re-enable your "MinimizeToTray Plus" add-on
7. Exit and restart

From this forum thread:
http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=1962329

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Steps reproduced here:
1. Disable "MinimizeToTray Plus" in menu "Tools/Add-Ons/"
2. Exit Thunderbird (Be sure that the process is not running)
3. Open Thunderbird (In my case, I had the same two windows problem the first time)
4. Now Thunderbird runs without the MinimizeToTray Plus add-on.
5. Close one of the window.
6. Re-enable your "MinimizeToTray Plus" add-on
7. Exit and restart

Comment: I had a similar behaviour, for me it was caused by the FireTray extension. For the more experienced: You can also solve it by manually editing the `session.json`: https://binfalse.de/2016/09/25/thunderbird-opens-multiple-windows-on-startup/

Comment: Thanks! Fixed the issue with FireTray.  It was driving me crazy!

Comment: Had this issue with FireTray aswell, following the steps solved it.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same on one of the machine I manage and the solution was pretty simple in the end. On one of the two windows just do file->Close. It closes just that window and not the other. Then close TB and reopen it.

I've seen quite a lot of mention of problems with add-ons, but in this case there were none and none of the other solutions worked.

Ian

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. Ctl + W or File>Close to close all extra tabs and windows. On next resart, only the last one is restored

Answer (score 3):

In preferences of FireTray (my version is 0.4.8) please check the field:

`[] Only last window can be hidden`

Answer (score 0):

What I did to solve this problem was to

1. Uninstall all Extensions (Add-ons) on Thunderbird
2. Restart Thunderbird
3. Reinstall all Extensions (Add-ons)

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this issue with thunderbird on Xububtu 14.04. What worked for me: Select 'Clear Recent History' from the Tools drop down menu, and clear everything.